# Spring MVC Jackson serialization throws NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Note : I tried almost all the solution available, but still not able to get it working.

I am using Spring 4 in my application. I have added jackson libs in my pom as below :

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.9</version>
            </dependency>
```

spring-config.xml looks like this(only part of it) :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Entity** (Omitted the getters and setters)

```
@Entity(name="Employee")
public class Employee {

private String name;
private List<Address> addressList;

}
}
```

I am using `@ResponseBody` in my rest controller. I am creating an employee with only the name (no address provided). After the creation, I am trying to return the same object back to the UI. But in this case, the address list will be NULL. I am getting NullPointer Exception due to this.

I have tried annotating the address field with `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` and `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`. 
But in both of these cases also, I am getting the same exception.

I tried different ways. If I create a custom converter and use it in the controller, it works fine. But I do not want to write that code in all the controller methods.

Any solution ?

Comment: I don't get it. If you are providing only the `name`, why do you expect the `addressList` to be non-null`?

Comment: Why do you have Jackson 1 and Jackson 2 in your POM file?

Comment: You should instantiate your List as an ArrayList or what-not, as advised by Hibernate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I was just giving one scenario. You can later add the address details after the employee details are created.

Comment: What's your JSON like in the request body? @Neil's suggestion is probably best.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan : Was just trying. Tried after removing jackson 1 dependencies, but same issue

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan : In the employee entity, I have around 10 other lists. Do I need to instantiate each time? Can't jackson ignore if it is null ?

Comment: Can you try, @JsonProperty("addressList") with private List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>(); or private List<Object> addressList = new ArrayList<Object>();

Comment: If I instantiate with array list,  then I think it will work.  I was trying to handle null fields

Comment: Finally, I went with instantiating the list in the entities. Other ways didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to go with instantiating the the collection with `ArrayList` in the entities and it is working fine now. None of the other ways worked.